# Ejabberd / elixir plugin and external dependencies

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

We are using ejabberd in docker, starting from official docker image. This docker image has ability to use custom plugins, that are in module_source folder. I changed compile options in Dockerfile to include elixir, now simple "Hallo world" plugin works.

However, I want to include external dependency, specifically [Pigeon](https://github.com/codedge-llc/pigeon), that manages to send push notifications to iOS / Android devices. I am not sure, how to make it correct way. I tried to copy Pigeon sources to /deps folder in my plugin directory and download all dependencies (like mix deps.get). However, how I don't know, how to provide configuration to Pigeon, that is normally provided in Config.exs.

Is there any way to handle those dependencies? I know, that I can run ejabberd as embedded in Elixir app, but I want to avoid this, to be able to use official docker image.

Comment: How do you want to trigger `Pigeon` from `ejabberd`?

Comment: We abandoned official Ejabberd docker plugin and created new one from Elixir docker image. So that now we have ejabberd embedded into Elixir app and everything works fine, including Pigeon.